# Datadog alert query to get failed kubernet cronjob from cluster

Tags: kubernetes, datadog

I was trying to get an alert in slack from Datadog when kubernet crojob  fail.
I have a query to get pod failure notification when its crashloop but not sure how to update the query for the cronjob failure

```
max(last_10m) :avg:kubernets_state.contaier.status_report.count.waiting{reason:crashloopbackoff !pod_phase:succeeded} by {kube_cluster_name, kube_namespace,pod_name,kubernetes.io/clusster/cluster_name}.rollup(avg, 120) >=1
```

Answer (score 4):

Can you use the `kubernetes_state.job.completion.failed` metric?

For example:

```
max(last_5m):max:kubernetes_state.job.completion.failed{*} by {kube_cluster_name,kube_namespace,kube_cronjob} >= 1
```

Note that there are two different tags, `kube_cronjob`, which is the name of the cron job, and `kube_job` which is the name of the instance of the job.

See also [the docs](https://docs.datadoghq.com/containers/kubernetes/data_collected/).